# Flutter splash screen shifts down due to title bar

Tags: flutter

I am writing my first flutter app and I have been trying to understand how to implement a splash screen. It mostly works, but there is a shift in the splash screen image right before the first screen is shown and I can't figure out why. I tried to show all relevant code and information in the following excerpts. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLe4CD9-Mso&feature=youtu.be) is a video of the issue.

Is it because of the title bar on the first screen of the app? My expectation was that the splash screen would disappear entirely when the camera loads. I'm assuming that's what's supposed to happen, but there must be a problem in my code. Any help would be appreciated.

**launch_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**main.dart**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final cameras = await availableCameras();
  final firstCamera = cameras.first;

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: TakePictureScreen(camera: firstCamera),
    ),
  );
}

class TakePictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
   final CameraDescription camera;
   const TakePictureScreen({Key key, @required this.camera,}) : super(key: key);

   @override
   TakePictureScreenState createState() => TakePictureScreenState();
 }

class TakePictureScreenState extends State<TakePictureScreen> {
  CameraController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = CameraController(widget.camera, ResolutionPreset.medium);
    _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Test Camera App')),
      body: FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: _initializeControllerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          ...
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
        onPressed: () async {
          ...
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you happened to have an AppBar in your TakePictureScreen?

Comment: @CheunYee Yes, there is an app bar. I thought the splash screen would be hidden by the time the app bar loads, but it does seem to be causing the problem somehow.

Comment: I added more code to show the `AppBar` instantiation.

Comment: Can you confirm this is not happening if you remove the `AppBar`?

Comment: Good question. I didn't think to try that. I commented out the `AppBar` and the picture still shifted downward.

Comment: I have same problem. did you find any solution?

Comment: I think this happens only with debug apk and not in release apk. Kindly try with release apk

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, so after search around the net find a solution [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47634#issuecomment-575844263)

add to your theme the line **android:windowDisablePreview to true**:

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
</style>
```